# Can't use USB external hard drive connected to Raspberry Pi 4 for Time Machine on macOS

Tags: macos, raspberry-pi, time-machine

I followed [this guide](https://gregology.net/2018/09/raspberry-pi-time-machine/) to a tee but haven’t been able to add the drive to my Time Machine. I see it in the Time Machine settings, but get this error:

> “You do not have the necessary read, write and append privileges on the selected network backup disk.”

I suspect it might be an issue with either the `fstab` file or the Netatalk configurations:

`/etc/fstab`:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults      

    0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p6  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p7  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that

UUID=<UUID-OF-MY-DRIVE> /media/tm hfsplus force,rw,user,noauto,nofail 0 0
```

Netatalk `AFP.conf`:

```
; Netatalk 3.x configuration file
;

[Global]
  mimic model = TimeCapsule6,106

[Homes]
  basedir regex = /home

[My Wifi Time Capsule]
 path = /media/tm
 time machine = yes
```

I also ran the `sudo chmod -R 777 /media/tm` command which is supposed to resolve disk permission issues, but nothing's doing the trick. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, the steps you post in your question needs to be done on the Raspberry Pi device, and not on the Mac device.

On your Mac, you connect to Time Machine via network

[image: Time Machine network]

If you have done that, make sure the **username** on the Raspberyy Pi device is added to “Allowed Users” under “System Preferences > Sharing > File Sharing.”

In the Finder, open up the shared disk, right-click and “Get Info” and add the username on Raspberry Pi device to “Sharing & Permissions”. Look at this [question on “Ask Different”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127665/you-do-not-have-the-necessary-read-write-and-append-privileges-on-the-selected) for more details.

Comment: Hi, couple confusions: 

1) There is I'm trying to add the username on PI device, but it brings up Mac users (i.e. myself and Administration), or Phone contacts. Do I need to add the pi as a Mac account first??

2) After I connect successfully to the server and mount the drive, and get to **Get info**, there's no lock, and it's a read-only volume. Trying to change access permissions on the Mac for the shared drive gives me a "The operation cannot be completed because you don't have the necessary permission." error. :(

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with this line? **UUID=<UUID-OF-MY-DRIVE> /media/tm hfsplus force,rw,user,noauto,nofail 0 0**

Answer (score 0):

[Hanxue’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1472478/167207) is mixing things up here. Those steps only apply when you are using a macOS as Time Machine target. The linked article clearly indicates that a macOS Laptop and a macOS Mini as Time Machine is used.

Since in your example a Raspberry Pi is used, it does not work like this. Your best bet is to:

1. `ssh` into the Raspberry Pi.
2. Check the chmods of `/media/tm` (should be 777).
3. `sudo /sbin/parted`
4. `print`
5. Note the digit that is attached to the backup HDD (usually 2, so sda2)
6. do `mount | grep /dev/sdaX` (X being the number that was retrieved in steps 3 and 4)
7. Check, if the device has rw state, if not
8. `sudo mount -t hfsplus -o remount,force,rw /dev/sdaX /media/tm`
9. A `sudo reboot` might help.

Good luck!

I am facing a similar issue right now, where I can connect to the hard disk drive, the Finder shows it correctly as a Time Capsule, but Time Machine itself fails to acknowledge the drive and let me use it as a target.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that's still stuck with the error

> “You do not have the necessary read, write and append privileges on the selected network backup disk.”

Even if you've already tried

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /media/tm
```

still, check the chmod of your time machine folder with

```
$ls -al
```

and see if it's been changed to

```
drwxrwxrwx
```

In my case it was changed back to 755 (or drwxr-xr-x) after I mount the disk and could no longer be changed to 777 after netatalk restarted.

**So the solution is

Check your access permission of the TM folder after mounting,

and set it to 777 before you restart netatalk service**

Good luck!